# Some applications suddenly cannot write to disk in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

Suddenly, some of the applications on my computer have lost ability to write to disk:

- MS Paint cannot save file in PNG or JPG format, but **can** save BMP
- MS Word cannot save a file
- MS Word cannot open DOC files (as that requires creation of lock file) but can open DOCX files
- Eclipse cannot install plugin downloaded from web

Other apps I have tried so far work fine. The ones which do not work do not work even with flash drive. It kind of looks like some permission problems.

I may have messed something in registries as I have been developing a script which modifies environmental variables system wide, but it can be completely unrelated. Any ideas what may have happened?

Comment: What happens when you try to save files with these programs? Is it nothing happens? Does it make a difference where you try to save these files to?

Comment: @Matt - I get various errors like "Cannot write, disk full" (Word write), zero size file is written with error message (Paint) etc. The location does not matter. Even trying on removable drive does not work.